# How to spin a polkadot parachain node and connect it to polkadot relay chain using a docker binary

Tags: docker

I was following along with this tutorial to run a polkadot relay chain and connect a substrate parachain to it.

I wonder, it there is a docker image available? so that we can spin a substrate parachain node connected to a polkadot relay chain with just one docker command.

Answer (score 1):

Previously to run a relay chain and connect a parachain to it you could use [polkadot-launch](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch), but that has been deprecated in favour of your choice of either [zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet) or [parachain-launch](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/parachain-launch). [parachain-launch](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/parachain-launch) allows you to start them with a single docker command.

Comment: I have my own development environment. Where I have deployed the polka dot relaychain up and running. I have my own parachain (that is obviously forked from substrate-node). I wanted to give user a docker command so that they can spin one parachain node that connects to the polka dot relay chain running in my environment.  How can I achieve that, what are the rough steps involved?

Comment: On the basis that you want to connect to a polkadot relay-chain node that is already running. I'd suggest using this example dockerfile https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/docker/polkadot-parachain_builder.Containerfile but copying across your your own parachain into the container instead of cumulus. Then you want to build the container similar to scripts  https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/docker/scripts, then to connect to the external relay chain node pass arguments like
https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus#external-relay-chain-node at the end of `docker run`